# Why does array match the std::extent second imp?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, template-meta-programming

The gnuc++ 4.8.2 `extent` implementation is as follows:

```
/// extent

template<typename, unsigned _Uint>
struct extent: public integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>
{static const int _ty = 1;};

template<typename _Tp, unsigned _Uint, std::size_t _Size>
struct extent<_Tp[_Size], _Uint>
: public integral_constant<std::size_t,_Uint == 0 ?
_Size : extent<_Tp,_Uint - 1>::value>
{ static cosnt int _ty =2; };

template<typename _Tp, unsigned _Uint>
struct extent<_Tp[], _Uint>: public integral_constant<std::size_t,
_Uint == 0 ? 0 : extent<_Tp,_Uint - 1>::value>
{ static cosnt int _ty =3; };
```

`typedef int arr[2][3][3];`

The `cout << extent<arr>::_ty` is 2.

Why does array match the second implement? And what is `_Tp[]`?

I want to know how `extent` works :o

Comment: But you know that `_ty` doesn't represent the dimension size, yes?

Comment: yes.I just add it to test which template it matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively doing:

```
std::extent<int[2][3][3]>
```

In the second template, instantiating extent accepts a template parameter of an array with a known size (**_Tp[_Size**]). This ***is*** what you have.

In the third template, instantiating extent accepts a template parameter of an array with unknown size (**_Tp[]**). This ***is not*** what you have.

Now for the first template, It becomes more obvious that this is a 'default' template to be used when a non-array type is used to instantiate extent. This ***is not*** what you have.

To answer your second question, **_Tp[]** represents an array type of unknown size, like **int[]**.

Comment: eh...  but I just give one template param.the extent declare:  template<typename, unsigned = 0>struct extent; the second template require three param.I don't understand why it can matched

Comment: Are you asking for clarification?

Comment: what dose the second param _Uint mean? :)

Comment: The template parameter "unsigned _Uint" means unsigned integral type.

Comment: didn't _Tp shoule be int(*)[3][3]? why it was int

Comment: @Davis-King to answer your question, "_Tp should be int(*)[3][3]...?", the conversion of array types to qualified pointer types happens when arrays are used as function parameters, but not template parameters.